# Android RuntimeException at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Tags: android

The below log is copied from Google Play Console Crash log.
This is for: **Android 8.1**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2991)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3069)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1763)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:192)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6817)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:445)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:875)
```

Please help me regarding this!